# Created multiple JAR files in ant

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am trying to create 4 separate jar files in one ant task but I am unsure how to do so.  Is it something I have to add in the manifest?  I want to be able to have one jar task but be able to run my java programs prob1 prob2 prob3 and prob4 separately.  Is that possible?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the jar task I have now:

```
<target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/prob1.jar" basedir="build/classes" includes="build/classes/*">
        <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="prob1"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like copy-pasting, you can create a macro for your `jar` task:

```
<macrodef name="create.jar">
    <attribute name="name"/>
    <sequential>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/@{name}.jar" basedir="build/classes"
             includes="build/classes/*">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="@{name}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

And use it like this:

```
<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <create.jar name="prob1"/>
    <create.jar name="prob2"/>
    <create.jar name="prob3"/>
    <create.jar name="prob4"/>
</target>
```

An alternative would be in use [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) library which provides a [for loop](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) for you:

```
<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <for list="1,2,3,4" param="num">
        <sequential>
            <jar destfile="build/jar/prob@{num}.jar" basedir="build/classes"
                 includes="build/classes/*">
                <manifest>
                    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="prob@{num}"/>
                </manifest>
            </jar>
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```

Comment: the macrodef is the way to go - ant-contrib is never the path. Trying to make ant a scripting language will lead to tears.